# IntelliJ IDEA and Gradle auto download

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, build-tools

I am new to Gradle as a build tool and I just don't get the interaction of Gradle and IntelliJ IDEA.

I started a simple Java project and wanted to use Lombok in it.

Ok, easy, just download the plugin and activate annotation processing. Easy.
[image]
[image]

Nope!

[image]

Ok, edit gradle.build they say:

[image]

Rebuild... nope!

See, what IntelliJ recommends here... aha... ok... add libraries to classpath they say:

[image]

Ahhhhh! :-)

[image]

**BUT** isn't this last step just the manual version of what a build tool is supposed to do if I told it to?

I don't get it...

Comment: What IDE and Gradle version do you use? Make sure to use latest IDE version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download and Gradle version >= 5.2

Comment: Gradle 5.3.1 and IDEA 2019.1

Comment: Not reproducible. Please provide a sample project where it does not work.